# How to configure Nativescript job on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, teamcity, nativescript

I have been trying to find some information about how to setup CI for Nativescritp App, but unfortunately no information available... So I have been trying to configure Jenkins by executing bash and python script to install dependencies and trigger {NS} build, but Jenkins environment does not recognize the 'tns' command and there is no way to setup env var.

I found [this source](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/development-tools/continuous-integration/configure-jenkins), which is now deprecated as the platform is not available. Maybe someone was able to setup CI and trigger Android/iOS build with Jenkins/TeamCity?

**EDITED**

So I was playing with Jenkins, and I managed to run Jenkins jobs on Windows 10 even though they were failing. So the way I did it I created a batch file to execute a set of *tns* commands, however, when I try to do it on macOS with the same logic only with bash script Jenkins is not able to pick up {NS} package. The script works from terminal, but fails on Jenkins...

Also, I tried to use NodeJS build, but the error from *tns* command was that I haven`t set up my plugin with all the dependencies required for local, which is not true...

I want my build server running on macOS to enable Android and iOS builds, however, it fails. Maybe someone could provide a set of instructions on how to set up Jenkinsor(or TeamCity) for macOS builds?

Comment: If `tns` is not detected within Jenkins it must be something to do with your Node plugin setup, configure it to right path.

Comment: I`ve just checked, my node is installed in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin . The same path is set on Jenkins under Node Plugin installation path

Comment: I`ve just notived that I was pointing to npm... But changig to the right node path didn`t resolve the issue. My shell script still fails